# How to delete temporary MapReduce collections in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, document, temporary

Is there anyway I can delete all the temporary map reduce collections? I [read](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce) you can pass a parameter boolean, to either keep or delete the collections. ut the parameter is for the shell, and I use the java drivers. Therefore, I cant set the collection to delete upon completion of the query. Is there any shell command to delete all?

```
db.collections.help()
```

does not list any command related with that.

Show below is a sample of the collections I have.

```
tmp.mr.mapreduce_1289483912_1
tmp.mr.mapreduce_1289483918_2
tmp.mr.mapreduce_1289483919_3
tmp.mr.mapreduce_1289483974_4
tmp.mr.mapreduce_1289483977_5
tmp.mr.mapreduce_1289484057_6
tmp.mr.mapreduce_1289484058_7
tmp.mr.mapreduce_1289484147_8
tmp.mr.mapreduce_1289484148_9
tmp.mr.mapreduce_1289541146_10
tmp.mr.mapreduce_1289541150_11
tmp.mr.mapreduce_1289542389_12
tmp.mr.mapreduce_1289542390_13
tmp.mr.mapreduce_1289543164_14
tmp.mr.mapreduce_1289543165_15
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB remove mapreduce collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163157/mongodb-remove-mapreduce-collection)

Comment: I am sorry, but that question is a duplicate of mine, because I posted first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They should be deleted when the connection to the database is closed. See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163157/mongodb-remove-mapreduce-collection) for details and a way to delete them manually.