# MongoDB remove mapreduce collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Due to error in client code, mongodb have created many "mr.mapreduce...." collections, how to remove them all (by mask maybe).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I run script in interactive shell:

```
function f() {
    var names = db.getCollectionNames();
    for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
    if(names[i].indexOf("mr.") == 0){
    db[names[i]].drop();}}};
f();
```

It resolved my problem.

Comment: copied the same code, but did not work for me :( EDIT: the name was different. It works now. Thanks.

Comment: Good idea. You might want to address the cause of the issue in the long-term though. Creating (and leaving) a load of temporary collections for manual cleanup is probably not ideal.

Comment: You should write > if(names[i].indexOf("tmp.mr.") == 0){ < because collections has names like tmp.mr.mapreduce_1295256376_56_inc

Comment: for version `3.2.x` it has changed to `if(names[i].indexOf("tmp.mrs.") == 0)`

Answer (score 3):

Temporary map-reduce table should be cleaned up when the connection which created them is closed:

> map/reduce is invoked via a database
>   command.  The database creates a
>   temporary collection to hold output of
>   the operation. The collection is
>   cleaned up when the client connection
>   closes, or when explicitly dropped.
>   Alternatively, one can specify a
>   permanent output collection name.  map
>   and reduce functions are written in
>   JavaScript and execute on the server.

-- [MongoDB docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce)

If not, you could delete them using them same method you would delete any other collection. It might get a bit repetitive though.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to achieve the same thing is this snippet:

```
db.system.namespaces.find({name: /tmp.mr/}).forEach(function(z) {
  try{
    db.getMongo().getCollection( z.name ).drop();
  } catch(err) {}
});
```

Pro: It won't try to collect all your namespaces into a JavaScript Array. MongoDB segfaults on too many namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary map-reduce collections should be cleaned up when the connection which created them is closed. However sometimes they remains there and increase database size. You can remove them using the following script:

```js
var database = db.getSiblingDB('yourDatabaseName');
var tmpCollections = database.getCollectionInfos(
    {
        name: {$regex: /tmp\.mr*/},
        'options.temp': true,
    });

tmpCollections.forEach(function (collection) {
    database.getCollection(collection.name).drop();
});

print(`There was ${tmpCollections.length} tmp collection deleted`);
```

The `drop.tmp.js` script can be executed from command line as follow:

```sh
mongo --quiet mongodb://mongodb:27137 drop.tmp.js
```